# How can I call a recursive function inside another recursive function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, recursion

I have two recursive functions and when I call one of them inside the other I get the following error `cannot read property 'date' of undefined`. Here is my code. I am using TypeScript.

```
export class FormFiller {
    
    fill(index = 0): any {
      const fillTypeFunction = this.date();
      if (fillTypeFunction) {
        fillTypeFunction('arg1', 'arg2');
      } else {
        throw new Error("Couldn't find a function");
      }
      return this.fill(index + 1);
    }
    
    date(qid: string, val?: string): any {
      const elem = $(el);
      if (elem.attr('ng-reflect-value')) {
        console.log('Data is set');
      } else {
        this.date(qid, val);
      }
    }
}
```

How can I manage to make `date()` recursive function to work inside `fill()` function?

Comment: Where is `fill` and/or `date` called externally?

Comment: I call fill() function in another file, and it should make date() function work.

Comment: You probably need to bind class methods to the instance inside the constructor.

Comment: Well, one problem is that the `date` method does not return anything, so `fillTypeFunction` will always be `undefined`. Since you're using TS, you really should have seen an error about that

Comment: Without a MCVE, this looks very likely to be a dupe of the linked question above

Comment: Actually the `fill()` function works, it calls `date()` function, the `date()` function works once, but when it should reproduce itself, it throws an error.